# Tail Number of a particular plane

Tags: aircraft-design, airline-operations, general-aviation, aircraft-identification, bird-strike

How to determine the aircraft tail number on a particular flight, using the flight number. I have been advised there was a bird strike on a plane I was supposed to be on, but air stewards told a different story to why we were delayed.

Comment: Hello Jackie, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com!  Can you provide more information about the flight in your question, such as flight number, date of flight, airport of departure and destination, aircraft type, airline. All that information may help users here to find the aircraft registration for you.

Comment: You can also try https://wildlife.faa.gov/search which collects voluntary strike reports. Use "export to Excel" to see the registration, the phase of flight and the damages. US only and about one report per day. Not much.

Comment: Hi thanks, the flight number was FR656, the date of flight was 6th April 23', the airport of departure was Malaga Spain and its destination was Glasgow Prestwick, Scotland UK. Not sure what type of plane it was, but the airline was Ryanair.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look the flight up on a flight tracking website such as [flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com) or [flightaware](https://flightaware.com). They have information about the registration of the aircraft.

For access to historic information or aircraft registration details you may have to pay for a subscription, especially if the flight was more than a week ago.